# How to approach and solve harmonic boundary problems?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Find a function $\phi(x, y)$ that is harmonic in the infinite vertical strip
$${z: -1 \le \text{Re } z \le 3}$$
and takes the value $0$ on the left edge and the value $4$ on the right edge.

This problem is easy enough to realize that the function we are looking for is $\phi (x, y)=x+1$ because it meets the requirements, however I don't know how to solve these harmonic boundary questions algebraically.

The left vertical line is $x=-1$ the right vertical line is $x=3$, both of these are the real part of $z$, so we have $\phi (x, y)=A(x)+B=\text{Re } Az+B$.
When $x=-1$ we want $\phi=0$ and when $x=3$ we want $\phi=4$ therefore,
$$-A+B=0$$
$$3A+B=4$$
$A=1$ and $B=1$ therefore $\phi(x, y)=x+1$
Does this make sense?

Comment: Well, what does it mean to be harmonic?

Comment: @CheeHan a function is harmonic if in a domain all of its second-order partial derivatives are continuous and the laplace equation is satisfied at each point.

Comment: One mechanical way to approach this for simply connected domains (that are not all of $\mathbb{C}$) would be to find a conformal map to the unit disk, integrate the Poisson kernel against the boundary conditions, and then pull your result back to your original domain.

Comment: The main idea is that, since the boundary condition is independent of $y$, the solution should be $\phi(x,y)=\phi(x)$. Together with the fact that $\phi$ satisfies the Laplace's equation, you need to solve $\phi_{xx}=0$ with the given boundary condition. Note that now this is just an ODE with a general solution of the form $\phi(x) = Ax+B$.